Convert PDF to Google Doc
I'm trying to convert several PDF files to Google Doc with OCR so that I can read the data in the files.  The examples on stackoverflow use.
Drive.Files.insert()

But I keep getting an error.  Here is what I have so far.  Any suggestion?
function getFiles() {
  try {
    let id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    let folders = file.getParents();
    let folder = folders.next();
    let files = folder.getFilesByType("application/pdf");
    while( files.hasNext() ) {
      file = files.next();
      console.log(file.getName());
      readData(file);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in getFiles: "+err);
  }
}

function readData(file) {
  try {
    let blob = file.getBlob();
    let name = blob.getName();
    let resource = {
      title: name,
      mimeType: blob.getContentType(),
    };
    // Save PDF as GDOC
    resource.title = name.replace(/pdf$/, 'gdoc');
    var insertOpts = {
      ocr: true,
      ocrLanguage: "en"
    }
    let gdocFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, insertOpts);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in readData: "+err)
  }
}

And the error message.
10:50:09 AM Info    Error in readData: TypeError: Drive.Files.insert is not a function


Did you enable the advanced Google Drive API in your Google Apps Script project (in order to use Drive.Files.insert) ?

Yes  "Drive API" service is installed.

Try Drive.Files.create().

Looks like Drive.files.insert() is deprecated. It was used in version 2. In Drive API v.3 Drive.files.create() is used. Read it here: Import to Google Docs types.

Actual @Tanaike response to this question was more useful because it showed the resource object.
